# How to fix score addition failure

Tags: python

I'm making a quiz. The user has 3 tries to guess the answer to the question.

My problem is that the scoring system isn't working properly. If the user guesses the answer the first time it adds 3 points, which works. However, the program adds 0 points if the user guesses the second time when it's supposed to add 1 point.

I've tried asking people around me and swapping the if statements, so that the possibility of the program assuming the score is lost.

```
songnameguess = input("Guess the name of the song!")
counter = counter + 1
while counter < 3 and songnameguess != randomsong :
        songnameguess = input("Nope! Try again!")
        counter = counter + 1
if songnameguess == randomsong:
    print ("Well done!")
    answer = input("Do you want to continue playing?")
    print (counter)
    if counter == 2:
        score == score + 1
        print (score)
    elif counter == 1:
        score = score + 3
        print (score)
```

When the user guesses the answer correctly the first time, they are supposed to have 3 points added to their score, and when the user guesses the answer correctly the second time, they are supposed to have 1 point added to their score. If the user does not guess the score in three tries, the game ends.

Comment: Should it have been `score = score + 1` where you typed two `=`?

Comment: `==` is a comparison, `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is wrong

```
    score == score + 1
```

**==** should not be used but **=** should be used

Hope it helps